# The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

After updating multiple extensions on VSC few errors appeared in all my java projects in the form of

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved
```

or

```
The import java.util cannot be resolved
```

tried reinstalling the Extension Pack for Java and cleaning the workspace but both didn't work

OS: macos ventura
VSC: 1.82.1
Java: 20.0.2